# SVG path transformation resolver

Tags: python, svg, css-transforms

So I found about 100 SVGs that are incredibly badly optimized - I can manually reduce the file size by 50-80% in most cases. I now have a few ones left where there are just heaps and heaps of matrix transformations on paths which I don't want to resolve by hand.

Is there some kind of program that can help me with this? If not, how can I quickly parse and calculate this with a python script?

To clarify, by resolving the transformation, I mean taking a path like this: `<path d="M0 0v20h20z" transform="matrix(2,0,0,2,4,5)"/>` and producing a path like this: `<path d="M4 5v45h44"/>`

Comment: It is a sizable task to build a complete path parser that will handle all the various shortcut syntaxes that the path command allows and convert them into absolute x,.y coordinates - so you can manually multiply them by the various transform matrices - which are often stacked in multiple layers. But here's the documentation on transform matrices - https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined. There must be plenty of python libraries that will do the matrix multiplication once you have the input vectors properly constructed.

Comment: I think it is one of those *holy grail* conversions. I tried this for the 200+ SVG country flags out there. After 2 days decided to do them all manually; and after another 2 days decided I could as well redraw all flags myself... took some weeks; but its now a **29 kiloByte** Web Component: https://flagmeister.github.io/ that creates the SVG on the fly. So it depends on what you have. Do you have icons? complex graphics?

Comment: There's [this](https://github.com/svg/svgo)

Comment: @RobertLongson svgo unfortunately broke the svg. No idea why.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I wouldn't call matrix stuff the holy grail of anything. I mostly dislike the idea of building an svg parser. And nice web thingy you got there, but why js?  Why not just static flags?

Comment: Not matrix itself... a parser that does all you want.. I couldn't find it and took me too long to create, that is why I label it *Holy Grail*. As for [FlagMeister](https://flagmeister.github.io)... 300+ static flags won't fit in 29 kiloByte (gzip).. and they would be just that: static

Comment: svgo has dozens of options. You could remove the one(s) that don't work for you.